# Logging Function results from an API call - Javascript

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, splunk

I've written a function that makes an API call using AWS lambda and then logs the function result to Splunk.  My issue is that for some reason the result is not being logged.  I think it needs to be converted to an async function, but I'm struggling to convert it being a JS newbie.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
const detailedNotification = function() {
     https.get(newUrl, options, (res) => {
    let body = "";

    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
        const result = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(result);
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
        let json = JSON.parse(body);
        let output = json.items;
        //console.log(output);
        
    });

}).on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
});
};

detailedNotification();
```

Comment: First off, the 'on data' function should only have `body += chunk;`. Do not try to parse body in `on data` function; response is still incomplete at this point. Only try to parse body in `on end` function, where it is actually complete.

Comment: I made that update and was able to get the output to produce on my laptop. I will update the Lambda and test it there as well.  Thank you!